# API works in swagger but not in react native

Tags: c#, .net, react-native, android-studio, expo

I have encountered an issue with my .NET API. Normally, it works fine with requests in Swagger. However, when I try to open it on the emulator using the command "npx expo start" in my React Native app, the application runs, but it is unable to fetch data from the API and does not display anything.This is my code from Program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ToTable.Controllers;
using ToTable.Interfaces;
using ToTable.Middleware;
using ToTable.Models;
using ToTable.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var Configuration = builder.Configuration;
// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ToTableDbContext>(opt =>
opt.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
builder.Services.AddScoped<IOrderService, OrderService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IOrderItemService, OrderItemService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IProductService, ProductService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IPaymentService, PaymentService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITableService, TableService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IWaiterService, WaiterService>();
AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior", true);
builder.Services.AddTransient<GlobalExceptionHandlingMiddleware>();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

// Uncomment to use the global exception handling middleware
// app.UseMiddleware<GlobalExceptionHandlingMiddleware>();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseSession();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

and this is my code from first page in react native that i want to use this api:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, FlatList, Image } from 'react-native';
import HomePageStyles from './styles/HomePageStyles';

const HomePage = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState(null);
  const [apiData, setApiData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:7077/api/Product', {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'accept': 'text/plain',
          },
        });

        const result = await response.json();
        setApiData(result);d
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []); 

  const menuItems = apiData.map((item) => ({
    id: item.productId.toString(),
    name: item.productName,
    category: item.productStatus, 
    image: { uri: item.imageUrl }, 
    price: item.productPrice,
  }));

  const filteredMenuItems = selectedCategory
    ? menuItems.filter(item => item.category === selectedCategory)
    : menuItems;

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={HomePageStyles.menuItemContainer}
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DishDetails', { dishId: item.id })}
    >
      <Image source={item.image} style={HomePageStyles.menuItemImage} />
      <Text style={HomePageStyles.menuItemName}>{item.name}</Text>
      <Text style={HomePageStyles.menuItemPrice}>{`$${item.price.toFixed(2)}`}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );

  const renderCategoryButton = (category) => (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={[HomePageStyles.categoryButton, selectedCategory === category && HomePageStyles.selectedCategoryButton]}
      onPress={() => handleCategoryPress(category)}
    >
      <Text>{category}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );

  const handleCategoryPress = (category) => {
    if (category === 'Wszystkie dania') {
      setSelectedCategory(null);
    } else {
      setSelectedCategory(selectedCategory === category ? null : category);
    }
  };

  const handleLogoClick = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Cart');
  };

  return (
    <View style={[HomePageStyles.container, { backgroundColor: '#FFD983' }]}>
      <View style={HomePageStyles.categoriesContainer}>
        {renderCategoryButton('Wszystkie dania')}
        {renderCategoryButton('Dania główne')}
        {renderCategoryButton('Zupy')}
        {renderCategoryButton('Przystawki')}
        {renderCategoryButton('Napoje')}
        {renderCategoryButton('Dodatki')}
      </View>
      <FlatList
        data={filteredMenuItems}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        numColumns={2}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleLogoClick}>
        <Image style={HomePageStyles.logo} source={require('./photo/sumup.png')} />
        <Text style={HomePageStyles.logotext}>Podsumowanie</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default HomePage;
```

When i'm using this:
[image]
and opening on android or trying to open web i got error like this:
[image]
[image]

When i use debugger in my emulator and when i want to click on page where i fetch api i got error:
[image: error]

I sent to my friend this code and everything works perfectly on his computer so i dont know where is the problem

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Comment: i add this to my code
var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
        policy =>
        {
            policy.WithOrigins(
                    "http://localhost:19006",
                    "https://localhost:7077",
                    "http://localhost:5111"
                )
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
});
and this
app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
and still not working

Comment: Have you tried allowing any origin (wildcard)?

Comment: Yes i did like this:
``
var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
        policy =>
        {
            policy.AllowAnyOrigin()  
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
});
``and its not working

Comment: dont use localhost, try to use IP Adress

Comment: Do u mean at backend or frontend? Because i tried to do this but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Okey guys i got a problem with localhost ports and it was a little collision of ports. I just changed in launchsetting.json my application url to different one and it works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).